# Why the div wasn't center on the page?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

Doc type:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

Body:

```
<body>
    <div class = "site-container span-24">
        <div class="page-header-heading heading-font span-24">
                    <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="page-header span-24">

        </div>
        {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
        {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

    {% block js %}
        <script src="/media/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/media/js/main.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

It doesn't work even if I put margin: 0 auto to .site-container. Why?

`.site-container` doesn't have anything yet.

Comment: just a quick suggestion, have you put a width for it?

Comment: Can you list all the styles which are currently being applying to `.site-container` so we can help debug?

Comment: NO I did not set width for it.

Comment: @JMC Creative @Lionel Chan - He's using a CSS template, Blueprint CSS (http://www.blueprintcss.org/). It has already set up a default width, but he's using the wrong outermost `<div>` name, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outermost `<div>` should have a class of `container`, not `site-container`. Also, for the outermost `<div>`, you don't need to specify the number of columns. It is the whole number (24 by default) automatically.

See the [the Blueprint website's demo page](http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/sample.html), for example:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    ....
    </div>
</body>
```

See these links for more about how to use Blueprint:

- [Blueprint Quick Start Tutorial](https://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/wiki/Quick-Start-Tutorial)
- [A Closer Look at Blueprint](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/a-closer-look-at-the-blueprint-css-framework/)
- [The Quick Guide to Blueprint](http://www.blackrocksoftware.com/blog/quick_blueprint_guide)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a width on the div? It won't center otherwise since it would just expand to the width of the page.

Comment: But if it expands to the width of the page, then it's centered, right?